# Do people still use Ajax for a web applications?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am programming a full ajax web application and did some research in frameworks for SEO and history tracking. I found this one: http://balupton.github.io/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

It looks great but the last update was 4 years ago. Do people still use something like that? Or is there an easier method out?

Comment: Oh boy, they do. And I can only encourage you to exploit its benefits.

Comment: [That particular project](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-ajaxy) doesn't seem to be very active any more, but yes, people do still use ajax and the history api all the time.

Comment: When you added tags to the question, [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (now a synonym with XHR+JSON in many context, as XML is rarely used in context) was used - it is how the autocomplete options were made available. Likewise, AJAX was used for adding this comment without needing to submit/refresh the entire page.

Comment: Check out [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! 
So, could I use Angular.js or Backbone.js to refresh sections in a web application?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, AJAX (XHR) is used all the time in web pages. It is still the primary way that JavaScript in a web page makes an in-page request to a server.

There are now also WebSockets, but AJAX (XHR) and WebSockets have different characteristics for largely different purposes (with some overlap).

There is also now an additional interface [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) for making Ajax calls which makes some things a lot easier than before and this interface is promise-based rather than just using plain callbacks.

Comment: after so many years, do you think ajax is still the primary way to request server?

Comment: @RezaM.A - Ajax has become a somewhat generic term for making an http request from Javascript in the browser.  The modern interface for doing that is the [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) interface which uses promises instead of events and plain callbacks.  Note that neither XHR` or `fetch()` really has anything to do with XML any more, because you can retrieve data of any type using either interface and JSON is more common than XML these days for retrieving structured data.

Comment: Do you think the term "AJAX" is kind of obsolete? Making a fetch() request is the easiest thing in the world so it's kind of pointless to say "my site uses AJAX, hire me". It's like saying your site is ArrJ because it uses arrays. As if that was remarkable...

Answer (score 3):

The link that you send seems to be for a jQuery plugin called "Ajaxy". AJAX stands for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML, and is a technology supported by native JavaScript (ECMAScript). Yes, people still use Ajax for web applications. If you have ever submitted a form on a modern website, chances are it uses Ajax in some capacity.

Comment: Submitting a form does not require Ajax.  It can be done purely with form tags.

Comment: Isn't that considered bad design to use AJAX for forms? Wouldn't you want to apply full front-end validation to protect against attacks like XSS or SQL-Injection?

Comment: Frontend validation for SQL-injection is not of much use, you should be doing it in the backend anyway, so why do it twice?
Anyway, you can do frontend form validation with ajax too.